# How do I filter real-time active users on single page app having query params?

Tags: google-analytics, angular5

I've been working on a single page application for a while. Every user session contains a parameter: "id" in URL. Here "id" is an identifier for group of people who will be seeing some particular information corresponding to that id. I added script for my website for analytics. But It always show real time active users for the whole website. I want to filter out real time active users for their corresponding id's present in URL. How can that be done? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use in API the filters parameter like this:

```
rt:pagePath=~id=1234567890
```